# php imagefilter

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

i have a Q regarding php imagefilter. can i create effects that is almost like those [here](http://sixrevisions.com/photoshop/22-professional-photoshop-image-enhancing-tutorials/)

Comment: Some yes, some no, some maybe, some with a lot of effort. I'm afraid you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: Some of them, yes. Which ones have you tried and which ones did you fail on while testing?

Comment: opps sorry i wasn't specific enough..can these be done: cross processing, lomo photography, gritty effect, dave hill look photo effect, soft focus photography, movie photo effect, extreme contrast photo effect, vintage photo effect, enhance skin..

Comment: to add on, im not sure how to achieve some of those effect. i tried colorize not successful. wat can i do?? do i need to write customize filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe few of them... Some of basic effects you can get with [imagefilter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php), but don't expect that one single and simple PHP function (uses about 15-20 filters) works well as professional and very complexly photo tool such as Photoshop.

However, if you know algorithm how those filters work you can develop your own filters/functions (using GD lib or ImageMagick) but that's surely not easy job (for most of those filters). It's easy to create filters like invert, gray-scale or to filter certain color channels but if you want to twirl, cartoonize, morph your image... I'm affraid that imagefilter() can't help so much.

*P.S. that was great PS tutorial link, you can find almost all of PS image effects [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/03/a-z-of-free-photoshop-plugins-and-filters/)!*